# GRUB2 and kernel vga= parameter

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, grub2, parameter

According to the documentation, use of the `vga=` kernel parameter is deprecated as of GRUB2. The fact that some newer kernels don't seem to support it anymore on certain adapters is of no concern as the graphics card I have is seven to eight years old.

The problem now is that I would like to use a higher resolution text mode, such as 80x50 instead of the default 80x25 characters. Apparently all graphics (VBE/VESA) modes are out of the question for this graphics card (ATI Rage XL) - the list of available modes only shows `0` through `6`. `6` is `80x60` but looks horrible, so I'd like to go with `1` (80x50).

I've seen 80x50 and 80x60 working after getting the list of available modes whenever the default mode wasn't supported (with the default commented out `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`) and I was prompted to choose.

How can I set the mode, if I'm not supposed to set it on the kernel command line **and** every use of `GRUB_GFXMODE` (with or without preloading `vbe` module) and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` fails? Fails as in: screen stays blank because it's an invalid graphics mode for the card I have in this machine?

My idea would be to pass `nomodeset` to the kernel still, but the boot loader would then still have to set the graphics mode. And I can't see any options other than the `vga=` kernel parameter for doing that.

**Note:** the `vbetest` and `videotest` commands on the GRUB2 console will blank the screen and then the screen switches to sleep mode after claiming there is no video input. `vbeinfo` and `videoinfo` show a few available modes other than the above mentioned, but there is no mentioning of where this should be set. Also, when passing `vga=1` (without `nomodeset`) on the kernel command line, I see a very brief warning about it being deprecated, but it's too long to read completely - and the output doesn't appear in `dmesg`.

Comment: Related: [How Do You Pass VGA/VESA Modes with GRUB2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107479/how-do-you-pass-vga-vesa-modes-with-grub2)

Comment: The `vga` parameter applies to the kernel, not to `grub2`. No matter how `grub2` developer is trying to make simple complex, it still works as long as the kernels understand this parameter.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe it is deprecated by grub2, however it should still work and must continue to work. It works for me using grub2 and debian wheezy as well as rhel7.3 (confirmed 01-2017). Also according to the official documentation it is not deprecated:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/boot.txt

> If the command line provided by the boot loader is entered by the
>   user, the user may expect the following command line options to work.
>   They should normally not be deleted from the kernel command line even
>   though not all of them are actually meaningful to the kernel.
>
> vga=     here is either an integer (in C notation, either
>     decimal, octal, or hexadecimal) or one of the strings   "normal"
>   (meaning 0xFFFF), "ext" (meaning 0xFFFE) or "ask"     (meaning 0xFFFD). 
>   This value should be entered into the     vid_mode field, as it is used
>   by the kernel before the command  line is parsed.

And https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/svga.txt will tell you all you need to know. Below a few examples of resolutions I commonly use:

```
vga=0x31b --> 1280x1024x32
vga=0x34d --> 1600x900x32
vga=0x31e --> 1600x1200x32
```

To get a list of supported modes use:

```
vga=ask
```

For a 1024×768x24 screen which I found works on pretty much all systems and monitors I use (this time in decimal and in hex):

```
vga=792
vga=0x318
```

Comment: This works for me when I edit the `/etc/default/grub` by appending `vga=792` to the existing value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`

Comment: A Ubuntu update today installed new grub UEFI boot stuff and proposed a command line change to add `vga=current` along with crash dump stuff. I declined the changes but came here wondering what `vga=current` meant.

Comment: i confirm it still works and improved my experience in 2024

Answer (score 2):

The vga parameter is still supported with the linux16 and initrd16 commands, so if you change "linux" to "linux16" or "initrd" to "initrd16" you can get the old behavior. I'm not sure what other changes that causes, but it worked well enough for me. :-)

Comment: This is great advice! Just press e to edit in grub2, then navigate down to where it says linux and put 16 at the end. Then you can put vga=ask at the end of the line. If framebuffer is still enabled in the kernel, it'll probably switch away from fast VGA text to that mode fairly soon though.