# How to adjust TTY terminal window size in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, agetty

In my virtual machines, both Linux and FreeBSD, the TTY (controlled by agetty under Linux; can be opened by pressing <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> where `n=1,2,3,...`) window size is tiny (720x400), compared to the resolution of my screen (1920x1080). Is there a way to adjust this? VirtualBox guest additions are installed, yet still a tiny TTY size.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you may be looking for the `vga` setting for the entry in your grub config.  This question may be of some help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107479/how-do-you-pass-vga-vesa-modes-with-grub2#107554

Comment: Thanks, although that does have the limitation of not being easily applicable to FreeBSD systems, given this other, presently unanswered, question of mine - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480829/how-to-create-a-grub-entry-for-a-freebsd-on-zfs-installation.

Comment: Tried that and `hwinfo --framebuffer` returned nothing, so I cannot set a resolution for `GRUB_GFXMODE`.