# Missing /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Tags: kali-linux

I want to change the font size to 0x318 in run level 3. I looked at /boot/grub/grub.cfg but I can not see a line starting with kernel information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your configuration file. Also explain what you need more clearly. On most systems, run level 3 is when the machine is fully up and ready, so there is no grub there. In what context to you want to change the font size? What font? And why would you be using hex for font size? What do you mean by `0x318`? Are you thinking of [screen resolution codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114980/22222)?